# Cancel Comment button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, design

[image]

If I remember correctly, there used to be a button for cancelling the comment. It seems like it's gone after the new site update. It might just be something that I imagined (but I do have a feeling that it was there).

Anyway, if in fact it's something that I imagined, it would still be a nice addition because sometimes I clicked the [add comment] button to add a comment, but then for some reason I don't want to anymore, and now the big bulky comment box is in the way.

Comment: As an easy workaround, you can just reload the page.

Comment: On the other hand, it only takes up 119px vertically.

Comment: However, I do notice there is a Cancel option when editing a comment.

Comment: How is this a [meta-tag:bug]?

Comment: I keep wanting to type a comment into that screenshot.

Comment: @CoolGuy Depends if it was intentional for it to be removed. The eternal Bug/Feature battle continues.

Comment: It wasn't there before. I specifically remember being irritated at its non-existence.

Comment: I think the cancel button is only there if you edit your comment?

Comment: If this is a feature request, and if it is added, please listen for the escape key too :)

Comment: Disagree strongly about ESC triggering cancel, unless there's an are-you-sure.

Comment: @aliteralmind Agreed, it would be nice if there's a confirmation before removing the box.

Comment: There is no "cancel" button for new "answer" as well. Sometimes, I have found myself in a position where I start typing out an answer, another answer is posted in between and I have to then delete all my text in the answer box to void it. There is a "discard answer" / "cancel" button while editing, but not while adding a new answer.

Comment: @aliteralmind i _hate_ are-you-sure; what i want is the option to undo, rather than forcing me to confirm in triplicate every. single. thing.

Comment: @Mathletics are you sure you want the option to undo?

Comment: @Mathletics: Sure. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just confirmed with the devs, we never had a cancel action button or link. The only time you can cancel a comment is when editing an existing comment of yours.

Comment: How about making this a feature then?